# Host unreachable from Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.9.3, airbrake

For some reason our local errbit server is not reachable from Ruby application running unside unicorn in conjunction with nginx.

> ** [Airbrake] Unable to contact the Airbrake server. HTTP Error=execution expired
>   ** [Airbrake] Environment Info: [Ruby: 1.9.3] [Rails: 3.2.19] [Env: staging]
>   ** [Airbrake] Failure: NilClass
>   ** [Airbrake] Environment Info: [Ruby: 1.9.3] [Rails: 3.2.19] [Env: staging]
>   ** [Airbrake] Notice details:

Pings from server itself are passing just ok, production is logging with no errors at all, irb pings are also normal. I spent all the ideas i had.

Comment: This is very unlikely to be a Ruby or Rails problem. It's more likely to be a network or nginx configuration problem.

Comment: @theTinMan is definitely not a network error - pings and gets are passing normal. I have no Idea how could possibly nginx configuration affect posts from the app.

Comment: @Vladson, what was the reason of the problem?

Comment: In my case that was network problem. It was DNS server that increase response time to more than 2 seconds, which is threshold for timeout error for airbrake gem by default.

Comment: @petRUShka, it was ports mismatch in my case.